# How do I make a class that renders platforms while also sending coordinate data into a data structure

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2

So I want my platform class to be able to make a new platform every time I call platform.render(x, y). Then in this render function I want it to be able to store the x and y data so that I can use it for a future collision class. However, the program is calling this render function indefinitely. The only answer I have is defining a new object for each platform, but I feel this is repetitive.

**platform.h**

class platform {

```
public:
    int x, y;

    void coordinates(int x, int y);
    
    void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y);

private:
};
```

**platform.cpp**

```
void platform::coordinates(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }



void platform::render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y) {

    SDL_Rect destR;
    destR.x = x;
    destR.y = y;
    destR.w = destR.h = 32;

    
    int xBounds[2] = { x - 16, x + 16 };
    int yBounds[2] = { y - 16, y + 16 };

    MakeSquare::storeRight(xBounds, yBounds);
    


    SDL_Texture* tex = TextureManager::LoadTexture("assets/platform.png");
    
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, NULL, &destR);

}
```

**Game.h**

```
class Game
{

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    static const int width;
    static const int height;

    void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);
    
    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool running() { return isRunning; }
    
    static SDL_Renderer* renderer;

private:
    bool isRunning;
    SDL_Window* window;

};
```

**Game.cpp**

```
Background* background;
SDL_Renderer* Game::renderer = nullptr;
SDL_Rect srcR, destR;
Player player;
//SDL_Texture* platform;

platform plat;


Game::Game()
{}
Game::~Game()
{}



const int Game::width = 800;
const int Game::height = 640;
int cnt = 0;


SDL_Texture* tex;


void Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
    int flags = 0;
    if (fullscreen) {
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Subsystems Initialised!..." << std::endl;

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        if (window)
        {
            std::cout << "Window created!" << std::endl;
        }

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (renderer)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            std::cout << "Renderer created!" << std::endl;
        }

        isRunning = true;
    }


    background = new Background();
}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    player.handleInput(event);
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        isRunning = false;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

void Game::update()
{

}

void Game::render()
{
    //boxMaker(srcR, 0, 0, 32, 32);
    //boxMaker(destR, 0, 0, 32, 32);
    destR.x = 350;
    destR.y = 100;
    destR.w = 32;
    destR.h = 32;
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    background->DrawBackground();
    player.render(renderer);

    plat.render(renderer, 100, 100);
    plat.render(renderer, 300, 100);
    plat.render(renderer, 200, 100);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::clean()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Game Cleaned" << std::endl;
}

void boxMaker(SDL_Rect rec, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    rec.x = x;
    rec.y = y;
    rec.w = w;
    rec.h = h;
}
```

Comment: This is not how you usually do things. The render function isn't supposed to modify any state. Make a list of platforms and populate it once during init.

Comment: Also avoid manually calling `new`, prefer containers and smart pointers.

Comment: I thought everything was made in rendercopy. How would I make this in init?

Comment: you should have a distinct game object that represents the platform. Move the current drawing code into a `Draw` method for it.

Comment: Would I have to make a new object for each platform then? The reason I did it this way is so I could just make as many platforms as I want.

Comment: Do you think I could define this platform object as a list of x and y values and then store the list to make the rectangles for collision. And finally rendering the list?